# OpenNMT issue with PyTorch: .copy_ function not clear behavior

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I'm working with the PyTorch version OpenNMT and I'm trying to modify the Beam Search algorithm. I'm currently stuck in the  `beam_update` function (in [OpenNMT-py/onmt/decoders/decoder.py](https://github.com/OpenNMT/OpenNMT-py/blob/0d7f82eec75dc73877e8c6f9749fbadf8a8033cb/onmt/decoders/decoder.py#L406) file). When it is called:

`sent_states.data.copy_(
                sent_states.data.index_select(1, positions))`

according to the pythorch [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html) of the `.copy_` function it will

> Copies the elements from src into self tensor and returns self.

But, what is "**self tensor**" referring to? Can someone explain to me what this function do or point me to the source code, since I cannot find it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `self` tensor is the tensor you call `copy_` on.
In your example it is `sent_states.data`.

---

To answer the question raised in the comments: Why does copy not behave like assigning with `=`

`.copy()` creates a real copy to a new memory location, while assigning with `=` only stores a reference to the memory location.

The code below shows the difference in execution:

```
import torch

torch.manual_seed(3515)
tensor1 = torch.rand(2, 3)
tensor2 = torch.rand(2, 2)
tensor3 = torch.rand(2, 3)
positions = torch.tensor([2, 0])

tensor2.data.copy_(tensor1.data.index_select(1, positions))
tensor3.data = tensor1.data.index_select(1, positions)
print(tensor2)
print(tensor3)
print(id(tensor1.data[0]))
print(id(tensor2.data[0]))
print(id(tensor3.data[0]))
```

Output:

```
tensor([[ 0.5939,  0.8861],
        [ 0.7525,  0.1537]])
tensor([[ 0.5939,  0.8861],
        [ 0.7525,  0.1537]])
4583187080
4583187008
4583187080
```

The location of `tensor1` and `tensor3` are the same, while tensor2 has been copied to a new location

Comment: I thought the same, but if I substitute that call with: 

`sent_states.data = sent_states.data.index_select(1, positions)`

the Network behaves differently.

Comment: What does behave differently mean? I tried this on a simple minimal example and it worked like expected.

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't provide any clarification. I suppose (someone please correct me if I am wrong) that the beam_update function has to update the beam status, ensuring consistency during the translation process. With only the modification posted above, the network translation is different (lower quality) and I cannot understand why.

Comment: Is there a reason, why `.data` is used, and not the wrapping tensor `sent_states`? So couldn't you call `sent_states = sent_states.index_select(1, positions)`?

Comment: @francescopanini I think I figured it out and updated my answer

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know if there is as reason to explicitly using `.data`, because I tried with and without it and I've got same results. I cloned the repo and stared working on it, so I clearly miss something. Your response may helps a lot, now I have to figure out why it is such a big deal for the Network.